# Scope for loading google classroom students

Tags: php, symfony, google-classroom

I'm trying to to load users via the google classroom api.
I've loaded the courses for the authenticated user, but cant load the students in the course.

The error I'm getting is: Request had insufficient authentication scopes.

Ive added these scopes:

```
Classroom::CLASSROOM_COURSES_READONLY
Classroom::CLASSROOM_COURSEWORK_STUDENTS
Classroom::CLASSROOM_COURSEWORK_STUDENTS_READONLY
```

Comment: https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses.students/list#authorization-scopes

Comment: wow, how did i miss that! :D ty

Answer (score 0):

**Classroom Scopes**

It would be important to clarify with a community wiki for future references in case other community members get a similar error.

As suggested the correct scopes to load the classroom are:

```
 https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.rosters
 https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.rosters.readonly
 https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.profile.emails
 https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.profile.photos
```

You can also review the quickstart information of all the scopes and what they do for the OAuth verification process:

- https://developers.google.com/classroom/guides/auth?hl=en

Reference:

- https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses.students/list#authorization-scopes